# Animating Tiles In My Game

Tags: java, image, animation, tiles, 2d-games

I am making a Pokemon Style 2D java game using no libraries, just pure java, and I am working on and having issues getting a water tile to animate. I want the tile to update every half a second or so. I will post my main class, abstract tile class, water class, and screen class so that maybe you can figure out a way to so me how to animate tiles in my game.

P.S: Right now I am trying to animate a water tile. And all the sprites are for testing and will be changed later.

Code at DropBox: [`AnimatedTile`](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3yikgj5wxo74tjv/AnimatedTile.java), [`Main`](https://www.dropbox.com/s/odp04q64mmtjyul/Main.java), [`Screen`](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pbh8puqsa3lpet9/Screen.java), [`Tile`](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pnifaq3tvdb9hmz/Tile.java).

Comment: Are you using GLUT or equvilant?

Comment: You could use gif images

Comment: ya, but I would like to learn how to do it through code.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: *"Thanks, Hunter."*  Don't include sigs. in questions, they are noise.

Answer (score 0):

I posted my animation tutorial in other animation question although doesn't seem the other guy liked it so much. Maybe you'll find it more useful, I used java.awt only. Has a working example on how to animate images. In my method - all of the tiles for the image to be animated are contained in one long image, and by updating the X coordinate of the part of buffer to be loaded it is possible to scroll through the frames and achieve animation that way.

Enjoy:
https://sites.google.com/site/javagamescorner/home/animated-sprites

Answer (score 0):

[image: Animated Water][image: Animated Water][image: Animated Water][image: Animated Water][image: Animated Water][image: Animated Water][image: Animated Water][image: Animated Water][image: Animated Water][image: Animated Water][image: Animated Water]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.*;

class AnimatedWater {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                final JPanel gui = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,0,0,0));

                final AnimatedTile[] tiles = new AnimatedTile[8];
                for (int ii=0; ii<tiles.length; ii++) {
                    tiles[ii] = new AnimatedTile();
                    gui.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(tiles[ii])));
                }
                ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        for (int ii=0; ii<tiles.length; ii++) {
                            tiles[ii].paintImage();
                            gui.repaint();
                        }
                    }
                };
                Timer timer = new Timer(50, listener);
                timer.start();

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, gui);
                timer.stop();
            }
        };
        // Swing GUIs should be created and updated on the EDT
        // http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}

class AnimatedTile extends BufferedImage {

    GradientPaint[] frameGradient;
    int frame = 0;

    AnimatedTile() {
        super(60,60,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        frameGradient = new GradientPaint[6];
        for (int ii=0; ii<frameGradient.length; ii++) {
            frameGradient[ii] = new GradientPaint(
                    0f,(float)ii,Color.BLUE, 
                    0f,(float)ii+3,Color.CYAN,true);
        }
    }

    public void paintImage() {
        Graphics2D g = createGraphics();
        if (frame==frameGradient.length-1) frame = 0;
        else frame++;
        g.setPaint(frameGradient[frame]);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        g.dispose();
    }
}
```